# Dynamically create subdomain from your app

Tags: apache, spring-boot, dns, subdomain

I would like to understand how to create subdomains for a cloud hosted app (application created using spring boot) on-the-fly when a customer creates an account while registering with some unique name which gets appended as the subdomains, ex- sampleapp.ourapp.com

I have seen scenarios like modifying .htaccess files and apache configurations. But i don't have access to those files on the server. Is there something that I can do from my application side?